# How to find remainder when $ 975^{40153}$ is divided by $14$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I still find tricky this kind of problems.
I tried to do solve it by factoring $14$ in $2*7$.

Then, with Fermat's Little Theorem, I find that:

$975^6\equiv 1\pmod 7$

$975^1\equiv 1\pmod 2$

How can I proceed frome here?

Comment: Do you mean $975^{40153}$? For that, write `$975^{40153}$`.

Comment: Yes. Just modified. Thank you

Comment: See [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228/11619) for a description (together with examples) of most (if not all) the relevant techniques you need. If it weren't for [a promise I made](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/23508/11619), I would close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Fermat's theorem in these type of questions is not a wise decision.You may use a more generalized-[Euler Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersTotientTheorem.html).

According to [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).

$$a^{\phi n}\equiv1\pmod n$$

Where $(\phi{n})$ is the [Euler Phi function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

Now,notice that,

$$975^{\phi(14)}\equiv1\pmod{14}$$

$$\implies975^6\equiv1\pmod{14}$$

$$\implies975^{40152}\equiv1\pmod{14}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space(\text{As,40152=6}\times6692)$$

$$\implies975^{40152}\times975\equiv975\pmod{14}$$

$$\implies975^{40153}\equiv9\pmod{14}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space (\text{As,}975\pmod{14})=9$$

Hope this helps!!

Comment: It helped! Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Lindow Nice to help you!!Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

$\color\red{975^{3}}\equiv\color\red{1}\pmod{14}\implies$

$975^{40153}\equiv975^{3\cdot13384+1}\equiv(\color\red{975^{3}})^{13384}\cdot975^{1}\equiv\color\red{1}^{13384}\cdot975^{1}\equiv975\equiv9\pmod{14}$

Answer (score 1):

$\varphi (14)=6$ and $gcd(975, 14)=1$. From Euler's theorem, we get $975^6 \equiv 1 (\mod 14)$. Now $975^{40153}\equiv 975^{6692*6+1}\equiv975\equiv9 (\mod 14)$

Answer (score 1):

Then, $975^{40153}=975^{6692\times6+1}=(975^6)^{6922}\times975\equiv(-1)^{6922}\times975=975\equiv2\mbox{ (mod 7)}$.

Also, $975^{40153}=(975^1)^{40153}\equiv(1)^{40153}=1\mbox{ (mod 2)}$.

Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem (AKA trial and error), you would find the numbers from $0$ to $13$ which $\equiv2\mbox{ (mod 7)}$, which are $2$ and $9$, and then test for $\equiv1\mbox{ (mod 2)}$, which gives us $\underline{\underline{9}}$.

Answer (score -1):

$$975\equiv-5\pmod{14}\implies975^{40153}\equiv(-5)^{40153}$$

As $(-5)^3\equiv1\pmod{14}$

and as $4+0+1+5+3\equiv1\pmod3\implies40153\equiv1\pmod3$

$(-5)^{40153}\equiv(-5)^1\pmod{14}\equiv-5+14=?$

Comment: Very weird answer really!!:-)....

Comment: @tatan,  Not sure if I understood you clearly!  Please rephrase your query, if any